# Why does it show NaN or 0?? The operation clearly doesn't give 0

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long d = (long) (1-(factorial(364)
                /factorial(365-12)*Math.pow(365,11)))*100;
    
    System.out.println(d+"%");
}

private static double factorial (int num) {
    if (num==0){
        return 1;
    }
    return num * factorial(num-1);
}
```

It returns: 0%

And when I put it on double it shows NaN%

[I don't know why it won't solve like this so I can then format the result like ##.##%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHtfi.png)

Comment: `factorial(364)` is too large to fit in a double (the max positive finite value is 1.7976931348623157e+308)

Comment: i’m kinda new, correct me if i’m wrong but then I should change the type of the factorial method to long right??

Comment: long won't help you. Instead of factorial(364)/factorial(365-12), just multiply the numbers between 354 and 364.

Comment: i don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`divideFactorial(a, b)` returns `a! / b!`.

```
private static double divideFactorial(int a, int b) {
    double result = 1.0;
    for (double d = a; d > b; d -= 1.0)
        result *= d;
    return result;
}
```

And

```
    long d = (long) ((1 - divideFactorial(364, 365 - 12) / Math.pow(365, 11)) * 100);
    System.out.println(d+"%");
```

output:

```
16%
```